# How to develop dynamic iOS settings menu

Tags: ios, menu, settings, preference

if you are developing Android apps, you can just create a PreferenceScreen/Activity and then link some preference items which are declared in a xml file to that screen. So you can build different settings menus and call them from different places in your app. They all use the same style and the same mechanism to save the settings chosen.

I was just wondering, that there is no such function in iOS. We have to call many different settings menus in our app, so how do I archive this? Is it better to design one dynamic settings screen which you can call from anywhere in your app (filled with different information each time), or should we use one big settings menu where all the app-settings live. Is it possible then, to simply jump to "submenus" of this big settings menu?

Should I use iOS Settings Bundle to generate the menu structure in files and then display them in an tableview?

I could find some Settings-Kits like InAppSettingsKit but I don't like to use an open source library for such an important function.

Answer (score 2):

The settings bundle is the right way to add settings to your app.

It's a bit unusual to access settings from within an iOS app, but if you're sure you want to do so then InAppSettingsKit is a good a way to make the in-app settings as similar to the settings app as possible.  The fact that it's open source shouldn't put you off - much of the iOS toolchain is open source.

Comment: Hey, but I'dont want one really big settings screen. I need many smaller ones. I won't use the "back" button at the top of the screen, too. :/ I think InAppSettinsKit is for displaying all your application settings.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you want to make your app non-standard? Obviously it's fine to innovate; though if you do, you need to be prepared to make the rest of your app from scratch.  However, if your intention is to make your app the same on iOS as on Android, I'd advise against it. What looks right on Android looks cheap on iOS, just as what looks right on iOS looks gaudy on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing where I have an enum of menu modes. Each time the a table view cell is selected it changes the mode and redraws the table view. conditionals in numberOfRowsInSection: and numberOfSections: change the layout of the table and conditionals in cellForRowAtIndexPath: change the content, all based on the new mode set. I then spun the content of the table for each mode out into a JSON file and at the beginning read that into a Dictionary which forms the data structure that the table reads from.

I chose JSON as it's easily parsable with NSJSONSerialization